# What is the meaning of いて in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, て-form

I understand that いて is the て form of いる but I'm not 100% sure what exact purpose it serves in the following sentence:

> "こんな私でも奥さんにしてくれる人がいて...今本当に幸せなの"

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the て form ofいる (to exist).
I think it is used here to connect the phrases